# how to detect new contacts added to the contact database

Tags: android, contacts

how to detect new contacts added to the contact database

I find a lot of code on the INTERNET but do not work or contain errors.....

is there an idea not a code to detect new contacts add

I know my questions are difficult, but an idea or a simple answer only ::)

I tested this code but it returns errors

```
ContentResolver cr = ctx.getContentResolver();

    String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME };

    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");

    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            Toast.makeText(this,cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data._ID)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(this,cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        //  System.out.println(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data._ID)));
        //  System.out.println(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME)));      




        Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
                null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", 
                new String[]{ c.getId() }, null);

        while (pCur.moveToNext()) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Start!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.out.println(.add(pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
        } 
        pCur.close();

            Cursor emailCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, 
                    null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", 
                    new String[]{ c.getId() }, null); 

            while (emailCur.moveToNext()) { 
            System.out.println((emailCur.getString(
            emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA)));
        }
        }
    }
    cur.close();
```

Comment: This is just an idea, so I won't post it as an answer, but I'm guessing you can use Loader for that, as it monitors its data and automatically updates when changes are made, i.e. a new contact is created. Loaders are available with the support library, so you can use it on a lot of Android versions. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html

Comment: Please I do not understand it right, explain a little loader

Comment: is there any example for android Loader

Comment: Check out the link I included. It contains everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

First u need to register this receiver in your main activity--

### getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,   true,new MyCOntentObserver());

After that

```
public class MyCOntentObserver extends ContentObserver {

    public MyCOntentObserver() {
        super(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        Log.d("onChange1", "~~~~~~" + selfChange);

        //getApplicationContext().startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SendContactService.class));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
        Log.d("deliverSelfNotifications", "~~~~~~fg");
        return true;
    }
}
```